# How to prevent overfitting with regression using ranger (randomforest)

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, overfitting, caret

I use `caret` to train the model (on Boston dataset from the `mlbench` package).

Here is the code

```
set.seed(2)
ind=sample(nrow(Boston),trunc(0.7*nrow(Boston)))
train=Boston[ind,]
test=Boston[-ind,]

# Fit lm model using 5 x 5-fold CV: model
model <- train(
 medv ~ ., train,
 method = "ranger",
 trControl = trainControl(
   method = "repeatedcv", number = 5,
   repeats = 5, verboseIter = F
 )
)
```

When printing the model, it seems I have a good model

```
Random Forest 

354 samples
 13 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 282, 282, 285, 283, 284, 283, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  splitrule   RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
   2    variance    4.172443  0.8113023  2.702026
   2    extratrees  4.574969  0.7819608  2.946490
   7    variance    3.744418  0.8324785  2.475156
   7    extratrees  3.812538  0.8342013  2.478945
  13    variance    3.821406  0.8214275  2.517686
  13    extratrees  3.795269  0.8282988  2.465104

Tuning parameter 'min.node.size' was held constant at a value of 5
RMSE was used to select the optimal model using the smallest value.
The final values used for the model were mtry = 7, splitrule = variance and min.node.size = 5.
```

When plotting the model, I get

[image]

However when I calculate

```
sqrt(mean((predict(model)-train$medv)^2)) #  1.487133
sqrt(mean((predict(model,newdata=test)-test$medv)^2)) # 2.648461
```

I would like to know what I did wrong, and what do I have to do in order to improve the model. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You didn't do anything wrong.

The relevant comparison is test rmse (2.6) vs. the one obtained from cross-validation (3.8). So your model does even better on the hold-out test data than found by cross-validation. Possible reasons are the small sample size (i.e. luck) and spatial correlation across data lines.

Especially for random forests, it does not make much sense to compare insample performance (rmse 1.5) with validation/test performance as a random forest is very greedily overfitting the training data. Instead of looking at insample performance, for random forests you could consider the out-of-bag performance (an implicit approximation of the true performance). Since you are working with the meta-package `caret`, this information might not be directly available if optimizing with usual cross-validation though.

Comment: +1 in general but be more accurate to you reference to packages. `caret`'s `train` has the `resample` argument so that information is immediately available. From `train`'s documentation:  `resample`: "*is a data frame with columns for each performance metric. Each row corresponds to each resample. The `returnResamp` argument of `trainControl` controls how much of the resampled results are saved.*"